# objective-c audio chat application

Tags: objective-c, open-source

Is there any open source app out there that can do a simple audio chat? like share the ip of the other computer (not on same network) and transmit audio back and forth? no compressing, etc?

Elijah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's XMeeting (hosted on sourceforge), which is a full-fledged video conferencing program though.

SpyChat (also hosted on sourceforge) is a client / server chat room, which seems to lack audio chat though - you may however try to integrate OPAL into it (see http://www.voxgratia.org for open source voice-over-IP software).